# phonegap auto back previous page

Tags: html, cordova

I am using phonegap to write an application. I use jquery framework to combine different pages into one page. The problem occurs when I open the application and fill in the form, next page is shown.But it returns back to Index page quickly. Then I fill in the form again. The problem does not occur again. How can I fix the problem of returning back?

```
<input type="submit" onclick="location.href = '#page1'" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$.mobile.changePage('#page1');` from the jquery mobile framework

As stated in the documentation:

> Programmatically change from one page to another. This method is used
>   internally for the page loading and transitioning that occurs as a
>   result of clicking a link or submitting a form, when those features
>   are enabled.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: How can I write the changePage() when I submit the form?

Comment: Don't use form submit, use ajax to send data and on success call changePage()

Comment: I have done it.However I can't get the data from the form by using getElementByID. It shows me wrong message [object HTMLDivElement] . How can I get the form parameter?

Comment: @helloeveryone edit your question and include html and javascript, this way I can't see what you are doing wrong.